# Minimising lines of text shown on ion-text

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

**HTML:**

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let message of messages">
    <ion-item lines="none" type="button" button="true">
        <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col class="message">
                    <ion-text>
                        {{ message.text }}
                    </ion-text>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**CSS:**

```
.message {
    color: var(--ion-color-default-shade) !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px;
    max-height: 110px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
```

I want to only show 3 lines of `<ion-text>`. If it's anymore than that then I want to show an ellipsis so the user can click on it to view more. However, my code above does not seem to display the HTML in ellipses. Not sure what I'm missing. Any advice would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. here `nowrap` will make sure that text will never wrap to the next line and add `!important` to **`ellipsis`**.

```
.message {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  width: 150px !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
  color: var(--ion-color-default-shade) !important;
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: `white-space: nowrap !important;` completely messes up the layout. It completely hides the long message and the text ends up being all on one line

Answer (score 0):

`text-overflow: ellipsis` works with `white-space: nowrap` CSS. Its a one line event. If, however, you want to use ellipsis on multi line text as would be the case here – then don't expect to have any fun. CSS has no standard method for doing this.

But, you may manage it via java script with the character count.